# JQuery: How to apply a class to a specific data onclick of radio button inside that row in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table which has records. I am trying to apply a css class to a data inside a table row onclick of radio button in that row. But what is happening is the css gets applied to all the records.

Now as we can see below for the TR having value as lion i want the disabled class to be applied to that span class only when i click on the radio button of that field row.

But what is happening is the disabled class gets applied to that span class but in all the rows. I want that class applied to that row only.

Below is an example and what I tried:

```js
    $('tr').click(function() {
      $('.show-animals .animal-click').addClass('disabled');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="label show-animals" id="animalClass">
      <div class="animal-data">
        <span class="animal-click disabled">No</span>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" value="Lion">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="label show-animals" id="animalClass">
      <div class="animal-data">
        <span class="animal-click">No</span>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" value="Tiger">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="label show-animals" id="animalClass">
      <div class="animal-data">
        <span class="animal-click">No</span>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" value="Hen">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Please guide.

Comment: Your's is invalid HTML. __Identifiers must be unique in HTML__ and You are binding event handler to all `tr` elements. I would recommend you add a common class  to target `tr`

Comment: Check out my answer mate and I will edit your snippet again make sure you dont have a closing tag for `input` tags next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out what I have done here mate http://jsfiddle.net/SCK5A/3434/

```
$('.show-animals .animal-click').on('click',function(){
 $(this).toggleClass('disabled');
})
```

Comment: Morelese Rubillos: Its not workin. I need it onclick of radio button click on a row to add class.

Comment: how come there is no radio button on your codes mate

Comment: I have just added the code that needs to add class. My app is in JSF. I cant add the complete code. so i just posted the code that is required

Comment: ok ok wait mate I have now updated my fiddle. check on it. http://jsfiddle.net/SCK5A/3435/ is this what you want ?

Comment: and tell me what you want to change mate

Comment: Thanks mate. i have anoter table where i have checkboxes. Just changing the radio to checkbox will work? If you can please help me with that too i will accept your answer. I thank you for your effort. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127613/discussion-between-rani-moreles-rubillos-and-sandy).

Answer (score 1):

Pick `.show-animals .animal-click` which are inside the clicked row using [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$('tr').click(function () {
   $(this).find('.show-animals .animal-click').addClass('disabled');  
});
```

Comment: Hello @void: This will help me onclick of the row. I need it on click of radio button in that row.

Comment: I have just added the code that needs to add class. My app is in JSF. I cant add the complete code. so i just posted the code that is required.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('tr').on('click', function() {  
  if ( $(this).find('input').val() == 'Lion' ) {
    $(this).find('.show-animals .animal-click').toggleClass('disabled')
  }
});
```

Better yet, use a hook (thru id or class attribute) to the specific span:

```
<div class="label show-animals" id="animalClass">
    <div class="animal-data">
        <span id="disable-me" class="animal-click disable-me">No</span>
        <tr>
           <td>
             <input type="text" value="Lion"></input>
           </td>
        </tr>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can simply use that hook:

```
$( '#disable-me' ).on( 'click', function( { $( this ).toggleClass( 'disabled' ) } ) );
```

Also, make sure that no elements share the same ID so you can reference them individually. Having elements with same ID's (id=animalClass) is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the perticular row for adding class.

```
    $('tr').click(function () {

    $(this).addClass('disabled');  
     });
```